# program checking for password strength (and/or operators aren't working/checking for symbols in a string?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords

I am making a password program that checks for the strength of a password according to its length and how many uppercase /lowercase letters, numbers, and symbols there are.

The following is the program that I have so far, however whenever I enter a password that should be returned as 'medium', it doesn't work, and instead I am given either 'weak' or 'strong'.

Furthermore, I do not know how to check for symbols in a string. Any suggestions on how  to achieve this and achieve the program? I only ask for simple explanations and suggestions, as I am only a beginner in middle school.

Thank you so much for the help.

```
password = None

print()
print("\nYour password should be between 6 and 12 characters .")
print()

password=(input("Please enter your password : "))

numbers= sum(1 for c in password if c.isdigit())
uppercase= sum(1 for c in password if c.isupper())
lowercase= sum(1 for c in password if c.islower())

if len(password) <6:
  print("\n\tThe password is too short .")
  print("\tTry a longer password .")
  print("\n\tLowercase Letters :  ", lowercase)
  print("\tUppercase Letters :  ", uppercase)
  print("\tNumbers: ", numbers)

if len(password) >12:
  print("\n\tThe password is too long .")
  print("\tTry a shorter password .")
  print("\n\tLowercase Letters :  ", lowercase)
  print("\tUppercase Letters :  ", uppercase)
  print("\tNumbers: ", numbers)

if len(password)>=6 and len(password)<=12:

  if password.lower()== password or password.upper()==password or password.isdigit()==password:
    print("\n\tYour password is weak . ")
    print("\n\tLowercase Letters :  ", lowercase)
    print("\tUppercase Letters :  ", uppercase)
    print("\tNumbers : ", numbers)

  elif password.lower()== password and password.upper()==password or password.isalnum()==password:
    print("\n\tYour password is medium .")
    print("\n\tLowercase Letters :  ", lowercase)
    print("\tUppercase Letters :  ", uppercase)
    print("\tNumbers : ", numbers)

  else:
   password.lower()== password and password.upper()==password and password.isalnum()==password
   print ("\n\tYour password is strong .")
   print("\n\tLowercase Letters :  ", lowercase)
   print("\tUppercase Letters :  ", uppercase)
   print("\tNumbers : ", numbers)
```

Comment: If you want a password to be secure, why would you disallow it for being longer than 12 characters?

Comment: `password.isalnum()` returns True or False, it can't be equal to `password`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Aidyn. There are a few problems that I see with your code.

---

The condition

```
password.lower()== password and password.upper()==password or password.isalnum()==password
```

won't ever happen. The first part `password.lower()== password` checks if the password is all lowercase. The next part `password.upper()==password` checks if it is all uppercase. The password can't be all lowercase and all uppercase at the same time.

---

`password.isalnum()` returns True or False. So instead of doing `password.isalnum()==password`, you would check if `password.isalnum()==True`

---

The line

`password.lower()== password and password.upper()==password and password.isalnum()==password`

Is not inside of an `elif` condition, so it doesn't matter if the result is True or False, it doesn't have any affect on the program.

---

Perhaps what you want to do is

```
   # If the password contains only lowercase characters or only uppercase or only digits, it is weak
   if password.lower() == password or password.upper() == password or password.isdigit() == password:
       ...

   # Otherwise, if the password does not have any symbols, it is medium strength
   elif password.isalnum():
       ...

   # Otherwise, it's strong.
   else:
       ...
```

---

You can check for the number of symbols by doing

```
symbols = sum(1 for c in password if not c.isalnum())
```